# Android build messed up

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm developing a game for some time now under cocos2d-js. I was able to add plugin-x and facebook integration to android build. a few days ago I was trying to add admob as another plugin but i came across difficulties. I tried, for the first time ever to add the project to eclipse and try to deal with it there but I came up messing up the whole build. I tried to remove all the additions (admob, facebook, pluginx) and to start all over, but I keep getting this message after compilation & on-device-installation is done:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 7513): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 7513): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41929ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513): Process: com.shirkan.PiuPiu, PID: 7513
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2djs from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shirkan.PiuPiu-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.shirkan.PiuPiu-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7513):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   Force finishing activity com.shirkan.PiuPiu/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity
```

Can anyone suggest what can cause such error?
Thanks.

Comment: a whole lot of suggestions actually: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: I could find only two relevant topics with an error similar to mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror+couldn%27t+load+from+loader+dalvik
Couldn't solve the issue using them though...

Comment: all the same errors, same reason. some object you use is null and you try to use that null object.

Comment: I've removed all my changes and started from scratch. Thanks anyway :)